# How to join wp_posts and wp_postmeta in wordpress ecommerce plugin retrieving only product title, product description and price?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, plugins

I'm using wp-ecommerce plugin for my own online ordering bakeshop (http://www.kingsbakery.mpkproducts.com/)

I don't want the way how customers made an order. I want similar order form like this (https://www.ssfamousdeli.com/order_ship.aspx).

I run a custom query in Mysql and I can only retrieve the product title and description. I use this sql statement:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 
        post_type like 'wpsc_product' AND
        post_status like 'publish' 
        ORDER BY ID Asc";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

I only stop there coz I don't know how to join wp_postmeta to select the price.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT wp_p.*, wp_pm.meta_value FROM wp_posts wp_p, wp_postmeta wp_pm WHERE 
        wp_p.post_type like 'wpsc_product' AND
        wp_p.post_status like 'publish' AND
        wp_p.ID = wp_pm.post_id
        wp_pm.key = 'Price' --This should be the meta key
        ORDER BY wp_p.ID Asc";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Hope this will be of help.